# O que é uma procedure banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, terminologia

A tempos venho acompanhando questões de que envolvem o termo `procedure` em banco de dados, então as dúvidas:

1. O que é `procedure`?
2. Onde usá-la, pra que serve?

Se possível exemplos de uso clareiam a mente do leigo(a minha).

Comment: Se não me engano, pode ter um entendimento diferente entre diversas engines, divergindo em detalhes. Entretanto, de modo geral implica um conjunto de comandos imperativamente ordenados; T-SQL inclusive permite que se use variáveis, laços e condicionais de modo igual à qualquer outra linguagem imperativa

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## O que é

Stored Procedure, traduzido Procedimento Armazenado, é uma biblioteca de comandos em SQL para utilização junto ao banco de dados. Ela armazena tarefas repetitivas e aceita parâmetros de entrada para que a tarefa seja efetuada de acordo com a necessidade individual.

Uma Stored Procedure pode reduzir o tráfego na rede, melhorar a performance de um banco de dados, criar tarefas agendadas, diminuir riscos, criar rotinas de processsamento, etc. Por todas estas e outras funcionalidades é que as stored procedures são de extrema importância para os DBAs e desenvolvedores.

## Quando utilizar procedures

- Quando temos várias aplicações escritas em diferentes linguagens, ou
  rodam em plataformas diferentes, porém executam a mesma função.
- Quando damos prioridade à consistência e segurança.

Fonte: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/tudo-sobre-procedures

## Exemplos

### MySQL

Imagine o seguinte cenário, tenho uma tabela com os campos nome, id e salario. Todo final de semestre a empresa fornece um aumento padrão de 300 reais e um aumento de 500 reais para todos funcionários com destaques, que recebem observações positivas, você poderia elaborar um procedure para realizar esta alteração nos salários, conforme abaixo:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE AumentarSalario(IN quantidadeObservacoesPositivas INT, codigoFuncionario INT)
BEGIN
    IF quantidadeObservacoesPositivas = 0 THEN
            <update que aumenta salario em 300 usando o codigoFuncionario recebido>
    ELSE
            <update que aumenta salario em 500 usando o codigoFuncionario recebido>
    END IF
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Assim você poderia utiliza-la sempre que for realizar esta conta para um funcionário.

## Resumo

Procedure são blocos de comandos sql, utilizamos para concentrar codigos, principalmente quando vamos utiliza-los mais de uma vez.

Comment: Tem algo que me incomoda na sua resposta. Talvez falta de exemplos? Ou então menção à distinção entre diversas engines? Menção a efeitos colaterais?

Comment: Não coloquei exemplos, pois a pergunta, era teórica, não vi necessidade, mas você pode estar certo. A segunda parte eu não entendi o que lhe incomoda me explica e vamos tentar melhorar.

Comment: Editei lá pedindo um exemplo ...heuehuehu Vlq a atenção man..

Comment: @LuizSantos sim, por isso +1, mas ainda assim isso me incomodou. Sei lá, só me incomodou

Comment: Então, pode ter sido uma falta de carinho minha a pergunta, eu pdoeria ter compreendido melhor e ter tido o carinho de colocar um exemplo ou citar mais dados, foi incompleta. @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado e MagicHat coloquei um exemplo, vejam se fica claro e da para entender bem.

Comment: MySQL o exemplo, certo?

Comment: Certo! vopu editar denovo, obrigado pela ajuda jefferson

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Obrigado pela edição e pelo auxilio :)

Comment: @LuizSantos, precisando estamos aqui. Sou neurótico com estética textual

Comment: Eu entrei aqui para ajudar, então vamos juntos nós ajudando e melhorando

Comment: Pessoal, já trabalhei com stored procedures em Oracle um bom tempo atrás e não sei se isso de serem "uma biblioteca de comandos em SQL" seria muito preciso. Primeiramente, em Oracle usa-se a PL/SQL, que é uma linguagem mais extensa e procedural que a SQL (me parece um superconjunto), tanto para declarar a SP como para chamar outras SPs, estas podendo ser definidas pelo usuário ou pré-disponíveis no banco. SPs não parecem ser nada mais que funções (recebem argumentos e retornam valor) acessíveis no contexto do banco de dados. Em Pascal seriam"functions" (que retornam valor) e não "procedures".

Comment: Extrapolo que o conceito seja semelhante em outros bancos. São persistidas (por isso o "stored"), isto é, são gravadas no banco quando criadas ou alteradas, a fim de serem posteriormente chamadas (e provavelmente há algum _caching_ das invocações). Então as pré-disponíveis no banco acho que até poder-se-ia chamar de "biblioteca de funções em SQL" mas as definidas pelo usuário também são SPs disponibilizadas no contexto do banco de dados e isso torna a definição um pouco mais ampla do que a definição atual dá a entender. Acho que caberia no mínimo citar que são **funções, _user-defined_ ou...**

Comment: **...não, armazenadas em banco e disponíveis para acesso no contexto do banco.** Então pra resumir, como minha experiência com SPs não é muito extensa, estou fazendo essa sugestão aqui via comentário para outros analisarem. Não usaria o termo biblioteca, porque juntando as _user-defined_ e as _system-defined_ já seriam no mínimo duas distintas para uma mesma definição.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [Rodrigo Dornel](https://materialdornel.readthedocs.io/pt_BR/latest/linguagem-sql/procedures.html):

> Uma `procedure` é um bloco de comandos ou instruções SQL organizados para executar uma ou mais tarefas. Ela pode ser utilizada para ser acionada através de uma chamada simples que executa uma série de outros comandos.
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE PROCEDURE uspRetornaIdade
> @CodigoCliente int
> AS
> SELECT Clientes.ClienteNome, YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(ClienteNascimento) AS IDADE
> FROM Clientes
> INNER JOIN Contas ON Clientes.ClienteCodigo=Contas.ClienteCodigo
> WHERE Clientes.ClienteCodigo = @CodigoCliente;
> ```

E esta é uma definição no site da Microsoft:

> Procedimentos armazenados são semelhantes a procedimentos em outras linguagens de programação no sentido de que podem:
>
> - Aceitar parâmetros de entrada e retornar vários valores no formulário de parâmetros de saída para o procedimento de chamada ou lote.
> - Conter instruções de programação que executam operações no banco de dados, inclusive chamar outros procedimentos.
> - Retornar um valor de status a um procedimento de chamada ou lote para indicar êxito ou falha (e o motivo da falha).

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so], MClaver89! Não é adequado copiar artigos como uma resposta. Queremos respostas originais, o que vale mesmo é a resposta que você cria. Toda resposta pode fazer referências para outras fontes que ajudem complementar sua resposta, mas o site não foi feito para fazer uma busca no Google e copiar pra cá o que achar. Leia mais sobre isso [sobre cópias de artigos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5466/100416). Você pode clicar em [edit] para melhorar a sua resposta.