# Gerar números sequenciais para sorteio

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou criando um sistema de sorteio online em PHP e MySQL.
Primeiramente eu crio o sorteio onde informo o prêmio e seus detalhes, entre eles a quantidade de cupons, com início em um número específico.
Para simplificar, vou sortear um carro e vender 800 números, que deve iniciar em 101 e ir até 900 (101, 102, 103, ...899, 900).
Em uma outra tabela, preciso gerar estes números de forma automática, e em cada um deles eu terei o nome do comprador deste número, telefone e email, que serão preenchidos posteriormente.
Como faço para gerar esta sequencia e gravar no banco de dados?
A tabela está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `numeros` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rifa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `numero` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `celular` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Somente o campo número deve ser gerado nesta fase, além do id, claro.
Já tentei diversas maneiras, não consegui. Agrdeço sua ajuda.

Comment: vc quer gerar os números que ganharam os prêmios?

Comment: acho que o problema é que você declara todos os campos como `not null`.. se só quer preencher o número, o resto vai ficar _null_, não?! se sim, não podem ser `not null`..

Comment: Creio não ter sido compreendido. Preciso de um script que preencha automaticamente o campo numero e rifa (que será informada através de um array) somente, massivamente em sequencia (101, 102, 03, até o final 899, 900). Depois disso, a pessoa vai selecionar o número e preencher os dados dela e passar a concorrer com aquele número.

Comment: Mas então, na pergunta vc diz que somente o campo numero deve ser gerado e no comentário o campo numero e rifa. Numero é a sequencia de 101 a 900 e rifa como seria?

Answer (score -1):

> [Procedures](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241659/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-procedure-banco-de-dados/241661#241661) são rotinas definidas no banco de dados, identificadas por um nome pelo qual podem ser invocadas. Um procedimento desses pode executar uma série de instruções, receber parâmetros e retornar valores.

```
CREATE TABLE `numeros` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  `rifa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `numero` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `celular` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

delimiter //
create procedure populate (in num int)
begin
declare i int default 101;
while i < num do
insert into numeros (numero) values (i);
set i = i + 1;
end while;
end //
delimiter ;

call populate (901);
```

- DELIMITER – Serve para marcar onde começa e onde termina a procedure, neste caso eu escolhi `//`
- CREATE PROCEDURE - irá cria a procedure, note que há parâmetros para esta procedures. Os parâmetros podem ser IN, apenas de entrada, OUT, apenas de saída e INOUT, entrada e saída. Os tipos de dados dos parâmetros são os mesmos tipos de dados do SGBDs ( INT, VARCHAR( ), TEXT, BLOB...)
- Em nosso caso temos a variável `num`, que será passada a procedure
- Entre os comandos `BEGIN` e `END` é que serão colocados os comandos executados pela procedure.
- Instrução While...End While - executa os comandos dentro do loop, enquanto a expressão booleana for verdadeira`.

A sintaxe formal da estrutura de controle de While...End while é:

```
While(Expressão_Booleana)
   instrução(ções)
End while
```

No nosso caso enquanto `i` (que começa em 101) for menor que a variável `num` passada à procedure (901) faz a seguinte instrução

`insert into numeros (numero) values (i);`